# Wi-Fi on fedora keeps reconnecting

Tags: linux, fedora, wifi, networkmanager

Here are logs of

```
sudo journalctl -fu NetworkManager
```

and

```
sudo journalctl -b -g wlo1
```

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2srXmvlQ_bM)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8yCI.jpg)

Additional info:
`wifi.scan-rand-mac-address` is set to `no`

Sometimes `nmcli dev wifi list` prints empty list, and i have to restart it so it will show my wifis again

Comment: Check this thread: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=273440 TLDR try to reboot with `pcie_aspm.policy=performance` as a kernel boot option.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Please copy this as answer, so i could mark it as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=273440) your issue might be solved by changing PCI-e ASPM policy to performance which can be done by adding `pcie_aspm.policy=performance` to your kernel boot parameters in GRUB.